# What kernels & packages do I un-install?

Tags: boot, kernel, storage

Okay, my wife's computer is apparently running out of space on /boot and from what I can tell in similar questions, it's related to unused kernels (which makes *no* sense, considering it's a *fresh* installation!)...

But what do I actually un-install?

[image: Installed kernels]

Other questions here indicated I needed to keep the most recent kernel (linux-image-3.13.0.34-generic?) and the backup/fallback (linux-image-3.13.0.32-generic?)...

So does that mean I should be removing everything else (linux-image-3.13.0.xx-generic, linux-image-extra-3.13.0.xx-gen and linux-image-generic)? Do I need to keep those "linux-image-extra-3.13.0.32-gen" and "linux-image-extra-3.13.0.34-gen" packages, if this is the case?

I was able to find plenty of questions telling me *how* to remove unused kernels... But not too many telling me how to *identify* (well, "confirm" really) what has to come off.

Any help in identifying exactly *what* has to be removed would be appreciated.

Comment: Is /boot on a separate partition? What kernel does she actually use? I'd remove all and keep the 2 most recent...

Comment: @Jan this is a follow up to http://askubuntu.com/questions/517466/ubuntu-claims-its-out-of-space, I think.

Comment: @Jan Yes, it is a follow-up to that question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to is run:

```
uname -r
```

This will tell you which version you are currently using.
Then run

```
apt-cache policy linux-image-generic
```

The `Installed` and `Candidate` fields should be the same. (If not, you have an upgrade available - make the upgrade). That value is the latest version you have installed.

Removing everything except the latest version *and* the currently running version is safe<sup>1</sup>. So in this case, remove packages which contain all the other versions (both `image` and `image-extra`). There may also be `header` packages that you can remove.

<sup>1</sup> If both are the same, then remove everything but the last two versions - always have an extra version as backup, preferably one you know works well.

Comment: @maru Your answer looks like its what I'm after... But there is a newer version (the canidate) and I can't install it because of the "out of space" thing! Shall I just follow your instructions, update, rinse and repeat?

Comment: @GregoryOpera I think you can safely keep three kernels lying around.  Remove all but current and latest installed, and then install the latest available. Repeat every two kernel updates.