# linux-image-generic missing - is this a problem?

Tags: kernel

After removing old and unused kernels from my wife's laptop as per this question:
[What kernels & packages do I un-install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517495/what-kernels-packages-do-i-un-install/517498?noredirect=1#comment702577_517498)

I thought I'd do the same on my laptop, since I've been running Ubuntu for *years* and upgrading to *every* version (.04 and .10) as I go... *Surely* I must have a pretty big list of kernels floating around by now.

According to `aptitude search ~ilinux-image` though, I have just one kernel (in addition to its associated "extra" package), and it's quite an old kernel too (well, in comparison to the wife's computer, at least).

More concerning however, is the fact that `linux-image-generic` appears to be missing - it's not even listed at all, like on the wife's laptop!

Should I be worried that this package is missing? Is it just `sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic` to re-install it?

Comment: Could be a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/449905/wrong-kernel-after-upgrade-old-kernel-still-installed or http://askubuntu.com/questions/364156/ubuntu-13-10-kernel-still-3-8-0-31-generic  ? In that case yes, you should install `linux-generic` (otherwise you are running with old kernels without security patches). Be careful and before deleting the old kernel check that all is working --- should be the case, but you never know, regressions do happen.